# How to show $\int_{k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sin({x+\frac{1}{x}})dx$ converges / diverges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals

How to show $\int_{k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sin({x+\frac{1}{x}})dx$ converges for $k=1$ and diverges for $k=0$?

I have that $\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sin({x+\frac{1}{x}})\right|\geq\frac{\left|\sin({x+\frac{1}{x}})\right|}{x+\frac{1}{x}}$. But this doesn't get my anywhere useful.

Is there a function that could bound and show convergence at $\infty$?

Comment: For large $x$,
$$ \frac{1}{{\sqrt x }}\sin \left( {x + \frac{1}{x}} \right)
=\frac{{\sin x}}{{\sqrt x }}\cos \left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right) + \frac{{\cos x}}{{\sqrt x }}\sin \left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right) = \frac{{\sin x}}{{\sqrt x }} +\mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{x^{3/2} }}} \right)
$$
so you have to consider only the integrability of $\sin x/\sqrt{x}$ on $x>1$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici My calculation was definitely not correct.

Comment: @Gary. Probably your first time. So, *Welcome to the club !*. Cheers

Comment: It it interesting to note that we can get a closed form:$ I=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{{\sqrt x }}\sin \left( {x + \frac{1}{x}} \right)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(t^2+1/t^2)dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin\big((t-1/t)^2+2\big)dt$. According to Glasser's Master Theorem $I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin\big(x^2+2)dx=\Im\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ix^2+2i}dx=\sqrt{\pi}\sin(\pi/4+2)$

Comment: your question is here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4133497/convergence-of-i-int-0-infty-frac1-sqrtt-cdot-sin-leftt-fra?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Denote

$$\begin{aligned}
f(x) &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sin\left(x + \frac{1}{x}\right)
\end{aligned}.$$

For all $x \gt 0$ we have

$$\vert f(x) \vert \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}.$$

As $\int_0^2 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$ converges, $\int_k^2 f(x) \ dx$ converges absolutely for $k \in \{0,1\}$.

Using [@Gary](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83800/gary) approximation around $\infty$, namely
$$\frac{1}{{\sqrt x }}\sin \left( {x + \frac{1}{x}} \right) =\frac{{\sin x}}{{\sqrt x }}\cos \left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right) + \frac{{\cos x}}{{\sqrt x }}\sin \left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right) = \frac{{\sin x}}{{\sqrt x }} +\mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{x^{3/2} }}} \right)
$$

we're left to study the convergence of the integral $\int_2^\infty \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}} \ dx$. You'll easily conclude that it converges using integration by part.

Hence $\int_0^\infty f(x) \ dx$ converges.

*Note: the statement of the divergence of the integral for $k=0$ in the question is therefore wrong.*